# In CasperJS how do you make wait work?

Tags: javascript, dom, click, wait, casperjs

Why this wait in 'clickOldShares' is not working? Even when I put inside a evaluate the the wait doesn't work. I believe that is a small detail with references, but I'm out of ideas right now.

```
function clickOldShares(){
  console.log("Waiting for Old Shares");
  element = document.querySelector("#pagelet_scrolling_pager > div > div > a"); 
  console.log("ELEMENT: " + element);
  if(element){
    console.log('click and waiting...');
    element.click();
    console.log('clicked!'+ element);

    //THIS WAIT IS NOT WORKING!!!! I DON'T KNOW WHY!!!!
    this.wait(2000,clickOldShares);

  }
  else {
    console.log("done!");
  }
  return element;
};

//Initializing Casper
casper.start('https://www.facebook.com/', function() {
   console.log("Entering on Facebook"); 
});

//Remote Message Handler - now I can see what happen inside evaluates
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  this.echo(msg);
})


//Facebook login
casper.then(function(){
    console.log("Login using username and password");
    this.evaluate(function(){
      document.getElementById("email").value = 'foo@bar';
      document.getElementById("pass").value = 'somepass';
      document.getElementById("login_form").submit();
      })
    if(this.exists('#u_0_2 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div > a > span')){
      console.log("Login ok!");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Login not ok!");
      casper.exit();
    }
});


    casper.thenOpen("https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=1063249230414580" ,function(){
    console.log("Open post with object-id");
  });


casper.thenClick("#pagelet_scrolling_pager > div > div > a",function(){ 
      this.wait(2000,function(){ this.evaluate(clickOldShares)});
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside of the page context (inside of `casper.evaluate()`) refers to `window` and not `casper`. You can't use `casper` inside of the page context.

You need to move stuff around:

```
function clickOldShares(){
    var elementAvailable = this.evaluate(function(){
      console.log("Waiting for Old Shares");
      element = document.querySelector("#pagelet_scrolling_pager > div > div > a"); 
      console.log("ELEMENT: " + element);
      if(element){
        console.log('click and waiting...');
        element.click();
        console.log('clicked!'+ element);
      }
      return !!element;
    });
    if (elementAvailable) {
      this.wait(2000, clickOldShares);
    }
};
```

and use it like this:

```
casper.thenClick("#pagelet_scrolling_pager > div > div > a",function(){ 
    this.wait(2000, clickOldShares);
});
```

Since DOM nodes cannot be passed out, you need some kind of representation that a DOM element existed in the page context. This can be easily achieved by coercing the DOM node to boolean with `!element` and then negating it immediately `!!element` to check if `element` is "truthy".

Comment: I was so close! But thanks to you, I understand a little more about the 'game of scopes' in javascript. Thank you so much! 

The image is not ok because is a lot of data. But I've call for getHTML to see and everything is there! 

I owe you a beer!

Thanks again!

:D

Comment: What about the '!!element'. I didn't know this in javascript. There is a documentation about it? Speaking of which, may I ask you a recommendation of article of Javascript?

Comment: The [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/1816580) reference question links to [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1816580), which is needed here since DOM nodes cannot be passed out of the page context. This limitation is a peculiarity of PhantomJS and not due to JavaScript.

Comment: Great!

Thank you!